# Running PI can no longer connect via SSh

Tags: networking, ssh, raspbian-jessie

I've got a brand new Raspberry Pi Zero W and have a problem. I don't think this is specific to the PiZero as Googling has revealed this to be problem with other Pi's. I've got the Pi configured with Raspbian Jessie, and running Pi-Hole, including the ssh server. When I first boot up the Pi, I can connect to it via ssh from my mac fine, connect to the Pi-Hole web server, etc. However, if left alone for awhile (not sure of duration) I can no longer connect with SSH or the browser. The Pi is still running as it's performing it's Pi-Hole functions, I just can't connect again.

Does anyone have any ideas, suggestions, or pointers how I resolve this issue?

Thanks, Doug

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly NOT a Pi problem.

The connection times out - this is normal, although there are various methods of keeping the link alive or increasing the timeout.

I find `ping`ing the Pi can often wake it up. I usually start a new terminal session to `ssh` to the Pi.

You can force the Pi to send regular packets by modifying `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.
This has `ClientAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveCountMax` but these are commented out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in my case Ping doesn't wake the Pi up again, and it ignores my attempts to start a new ssh session. I will look at the ClientAliveInterval and ClientAliveCountMax, but I think this is not what I'm looking for. I'm not trying to keep an an inactive ssh session connected, I'm trying to create a new ssh session after some time has passed since I logged out of my previous ssh session. It's at this point the Pi ignores pings, ssh and http connections.

Answer (score 0):

I had run into problem like this several times with my Rpi0 configured as a Network USB gadget. Although it responded to `ping` from other Linux devices, it refuses an SSH session. I ended up with a hard power cycle. Once it finishes the booting process, I can SSH into my Rpi0.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this isn't what I'm looking for. I'm trying to leave the Pi0 running, essentially 24/7 providing the Pi-Hole service. The problem is I can't ssh into the Pi after it's been running for awhile, and it also ignores ping and http connections. The later provides the web interface to the Pi-Hole service.